# Already edited htaccess to remove trailing slash but still doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel

I added a code to remove trailing slash at the end of my URL, cleared cache in the browser but still does'nt work.
I'm using laravel.

Here is my code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How are you running your application? Using a local PHP server, Apache or NGINX?

Comment: I'm using laravel. so i think local PHP server?

Comment: You should know if you're using the local PHP server or not. The fact that you're using Laravel doesn't tell us much, since you can serve that through any web server with PHP support. Also, htaccess-files are for Apache. As far as I know, PHP's built in web server doesn't read them, so changing the htaccess shouldn't make any difference in this case.

Comment: Yes PHP server. because I ran it in PHP artisan serve

Comment: Then you can't use htaccess to change the behavior of the web server. PHP's built in web server is very limited when it comes to configuration compared to a "real" web server.

Comment: So how can I remove trailing slash in laravel? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You can either do it in the code, or you can set up a local Apache (using something line WAMP/XAMPP or similar) to test your server settings (which is what I would recommend).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a local PHP server, you cannot use a `.htaccess` file. These files are used by Apache and are not read by PHP.

Try running your application on an Apache Server to test your `.htaccess` rules.